# Memory safest way to pull sub-arrays from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array, garbage-collection

I'm iterating through an array of arrays, pulling out the sub-arrays I need and discarding the rest.

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    if (oldArray[i][property] == value) {
        newArray.push(oldArray[i]);
    }
}
oldArray = newArray;
```

1. Is this the most memory-friendly way to do this?
2. Will garbage collection safely take care of the sub-arrays I did not push onto
   newArray?
3. Will newArray be scattered across memory in a way that could prevent this method from scaling efficiently?

Comment: You must first understand that no array existed in the first place, it was always a map

Comment: @fmsf well we don't *know* that; there's not enough context in the question.

Comment: "append"?  I think you must mean ".push()", right?

Comment: @Pointy yes we know an array is a map whose index is the map's key

Comment: @Pointy Arnolfini Marriage great painting :)

Comment: @fmsf yes I think I would fly to London for no other reason than to see it again :-) Oh and yes, you're right about the map vs. array thing; mostly I was trying to figure out what he meant by "append" at that point! Of course the *outer* array into which he's accumulating things is an array, and the outer object with the ".length" is *probably* an array; what I don't know is whether the contents are arrays or objects. I thought he might be trying to "flatten" selected rows into a single 1-dimensional array.

Comment: My mistake! This is just concept code - .push() is what I intended. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript prototypal nature makes everything be an object. And all objects are maps, literally hash maps. Which means that when you are "pulling", as you say, objects from one array into another, you are only copying their references.

So yes I would say it won't bring you much memory problems, if you drop the references (at least in modern browsers). But the garbage collectors are implemented in different ways depending on the browser you are working with.

1 - Is this the most memory-friendly way to do this?

If you drop the references, yes it is a memory friendly way to do it. You don't have any `free` like in c/c++, and for testing purposes on chrome i think you can call `window.gc()` to call the garbage collector. I think a `delete` exists or existed but I don't know how it works.

2- Will garbage collection safely take care of the sub-arrays I did not append to newArray?

If there aren't any other references pointing to them. Yes. Circular memory leaks were common in older browsers but with the new ones it's safe to say yes.

3 - Will newArray be scattered across memory in a way that could prevent this method from scaling efficiently?

Yes it will be scattered across memory because in javascript arrays work like hashmaps or linked hashmaps (if i'm mistaken here someone pls correct me) but the garbage collector will take care of it, because it is used to work with maps. And again you are only working with references the objects will keep in the same place and you will only store references in the array.

Answer (score 1):

1.no...   fmsf is mostly right, but there are some micro-optimization that you could do for page load time improvement, and for the time to check the condition.  If you leave oldArray.length in the loop, it will look up length on the oldArray object for every iteration, which can add some time in large loops, also instantiating all your variables at once can also save some time if the method this is contained within is called many times.
When someone downloads your script, it is good to have all the variables with shortest names as possible to have the least data transference from server to client.

```
var nA = [],
    i = 0,
    t = oA.length,
    s;
for (; i < t; i++) {
    s = oA[i];
    if (s[p] == v) {
        nA.push(s[i]);
    }
}
oA = nA;
```

If you want to get really serious, you would use a code minifier for the renaming of variables and white space removal.

2.yes, JavaScript is pretty good about these things, the only things you have to look out for is IE closures which would not be caused by your code here.   I have still found closures in rare cases to be prevalent in IE9 in odd cases, but these are usually caused by linking to the DOM, which is irrelevant in this case.

3.no, the only things that are changing with this code are refrences to objects, not how they are stored in memory.

Comment: Shouldn't the .length hoisting be handled by loop invariant code motion in V8 and Tracemonkey?

Comment: Doesn't that assume certain browsers are being used?

Comment: Moreover, technically doesn't bounds checking happen anyway even in your optimized version simply because all JavaScript indexing will entail a bounds check in order to figure out whether to extend the data structure?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous, please edit your comment and parenthesize the name of each object with the items in my example where you are referencing them in the question.  What I am getting from your question at this point is that you are talking about the bounds check itself and not the extra reference lookup associated with leaving (some object).length as compared with a more direct association of just (some length) saved as value.

Comment: The other way I interpret your comment is that you are talking about a bounds check at "nA.push(s[i])" which is a digression from your original comment.